# How to get list of available coupon code of Current Product Only

Tags: magento2.2, coupon-codes

How to get available coupon code of current product

Comment: I want to show list of coupon code which can apply to current product not all coupon codes.

Comment: On Which page? product or cart?

Comment: On product page I want show available coupon code of current product pagr

Comment: @Prathap Gunasekaran on Cart page is also useful

Comment: If it's possible to have available coupons of cart which can apply

Comment: I don't think any straight forward way to get that one, you gotta get more about salesrule table. We can get applied coupons from cart that's so straight forward

Comment: yes i got the applied coupons and all list of coupons. I am trying to get only available coupon codes which can apply.